# How can I identify symbols within an expression which are wrapped in a local HoldForm?

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching

Let's assume `a=b`, that is, a has value b. In a given expression like e.g.

`a + i + HoldForm[a + k] + l`

I would like to substitute - while the whole expression is being held globally - every symbol by its value, unless the symbol is wrapped in a local HoldForm. The form

`HoldForm[a + i + HoldForm[a + k] + l] /. s_Symbol :> RuleCondition[s,ValueQ[s]]`

returns `b + i + (b + k) + l`,

that is, all symbols of the expression have been substituted by their values, including the second appearance of a. How can I identify symbols which are wrapped in a local HoldForm and exclude them from this substitution procedure? Or do I have to take a completely different approach?

Thanks for help!

Comment: ``Developer`ReplaceAllUnheld[Unevaluated[a + i + HoldForm[a + k] + l], 
 s_Symbol :> RuleCondition[s, ValueQ[s]]]``  would probably do the job.  But what you ask is so incredibly clumsy, I recommend you rethink your code in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. This goes into the right direction, but I need to keep the outer HoldForm. The Unevaluated is not enough. Except for the substitutions mentioned, no evaluation of the expression should take place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ReplaceAll works top-down, so you can add a rule to your replacement to leave [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm) objects alone. Assuming the outer [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold) wrapper isn't [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm) you could do:

```
held = Hold[a + i + HoldForm[a + k] + l];
rule = {h_HoldForm :> h, HoldPattern[s_Symbol] :> RuleCondition[s]};

held /. rule
```

> Hold[b + i + HoldForm[a + k] + l]

If the outer [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold) wrapper is a [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm), then you would need to change the wrapper before applying the above rule, so you could do something like:

```
held = HoldForm[a + i + HoldForm[a + k] + l];

Apply[HoldForm] @ ReplaceAll[rule] @ Apply[Hold] @ held
```

> HoldForm[b + i + HoldForm[a + k] + l]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. And I learned a lot from your answer, too.